# convert JSON from google app script to flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i'm trying to fetch data from a range of two columns on google sheet
first column with numbers,second column text
to my flutter app.

i managed to make the the http request
by this line of code:

```
  var url = Uri.parse(
    'https:`enter code here`//script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=Bzv-qcg70rUkHCr4pjI_k_qlB9c5I_GjKS-U726WCslGZ0tulYSbfdD1DabRoVrrbDSn9rIS78vQxr33OOOjaAw4d4DcA8sGm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnBqJjZp2jp3I5Qlxq6dcbGTdqr4FTByb3YAAvkZxH-A03NfLQ3Ce8hucRs86AXu4Vcg63MBXANpH4BVmytCxmg24Mg9dF6sKjQ&lib=M7v_2CxFrrqdcmzthOkMrc1jilJU4QU4H');

   

 

void getData() async {
      Response response = await get(url);
    
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {}
      var feedback = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
      print('Response body: ${response.body}');
    }
```

when i'm printing the response body,i'm getting the whole data
now,what i'm trying to do is to enter a number to a TextField in the flutter app
and to get a result from the parallel second column next to the first column where is typed the number i entered.

=============================
update
i've created a model from my json data
this the model created from the website
https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

```
        class Note {
      late String id;
    
      Note({required this.id});
    
      Note.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        id = json['id'];
      }
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
        data['id'] = id;
        return data;
      }
    }

now this the new code for getting the data from google sheet

    
Future<void> getData() async {
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzU89ZEE0Y9sgEQZMZHSbX00M6hPdHOX6WN8IjQWa5lzgAzmAc4jZShpUfKbnJ5zm8J/exec"));

  var body = response.body;
  Note note = Note.fromJson(jsonDecode(body));
  print(note.id.toString());
}
```

and i'm getting an error when trying to run the flutter app on vscode
a new tab of browser client opened no data come from the google sheet api
and this a screenshot from the vscode

[image]

Comment: Can you add the response body you printed?

Comment: {"GoogleSheetData":[["order","id"],[123,"pizza"],[245,"oni"],[752,"gggd"]]}

Answer (score 0):

While working with **JSON data**

The good practice is to create a model for that and then just fetch the data through the API

creating a model and a class is easy enough and doesn't take effort and makes your work easy ;)

For **creating a model for your project**

VISIT https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart

Just copy your JSON data and paste in the textField and you will get your Model Class ready with just one click

for accessing the data

`Test _test = Test.fromJson(response.body);`

that's it.

refer image shown below
[image: Tux, the Linux mascot]

Comment: there is still a problem,i'v update my post

Comment: I still don't understand your problem. the link has a problem when calling the API